# Can't find track from artist and title name

Tags: musicbrainz

I am experimenting with the musicbrainz api using NodeJs. I want to get the track info of a specific track. I can do it with ISRC but if I try to search it with artist and title name, i get the wrong results.

For Example: Artist = Aphrodite's Child, Title = It's five o'clock

URL: https://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/recording/?query=recording:It%27s%20five%20o%27clock&artist:Aphrodite%27s%20Child&fmt=json&inc=

This doesn't return the right results although I know that this song is in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&` (a single ampersand) does not combine multiple search criteria like you'd expect. The [Lucene search syntax](https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_7_2/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#package.description) description, which [the MusicBrainz search docs](https://musicbrainz.org/doc/MusicBrainz_API/Search) link to, say:

> AND
>
> The AND operator matches documents where both terms exist anywhere in
> the text of a single document. This is equivalent to an intersection
> using sets. The symbol && can be used in place of the word AND.

Either https://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/recording/?query=recording:It%27s%20five%20o%27clock%20%26%26%20artist:Aphrodite%27s%20Child&fmt=json&inc= (two ampersands, escaped as `%26`) or https://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/recording/?query=recording:It%27s%20five%20o%27clock%20and%20artist:Aphrodite%27s%20Child&fmt=json&inc= (the keyword `and`) work.

Another note: searches via the MusicBrainz API do not support the `inc` parameter, include lookups and browse requests do.